# MyMonero wallet MetaMask wallet

Tags: mymonero, wallet

Can I send coins from MetaMask to MyMonero wallet? Because when I try my MetaMask wallet, I can't see my address and can't read it.

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask is *not* a Monero wallet, so no, you cannot send from MetaMask to a Monero wallet.